# Integrate Flattr button into Software

Tags: flattr

Is it allowed to integrate a Flattr button directly into a software for example in the credits section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing that prevents you from integrating Flattr into software, Flattr even encourages it. If you wan't to look into more information in how you integrate you can head over to Flattrs [developer site](http://developers.flattr.net).

Basically there is two ways you can implement a Flattr button, either use the button javascript and integrate that into a browser or you can connect to our REST API. The API gives you alot more power over what you can do but at the same time it is a little more to implement. But all this is described on the [developer site](http://developers.flattr.net).

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could see in the terms of use you are not breaking any rules, but you better take a look by your self.  Regardless, that button in your software will need to bring you to the Flattr web services (aka webpage).  I hope that helps.